# Oracle Insert with .sql file using SQLPLUS for German Language

Tags: oracle, insert

I have data in German Language and when I tried to insert records directly using Oracle  SQLPLUS data inserted successfully in table but with same Insert statement in .SQL file put junk character in table.
Please suggest me how I can execute insert statement using .sql file.

Comment: Assuming you're running the file from the same SQL*Plus session where you can run the query directly, what is the character encoding of the file itself? That may not be obvious and may depend on your platform and the editor you're using to create the file; on Windows I believe Notepad++ generally works and can give you that information about the file, or there's vim on various platforms.

Comment: Hi Alex, I am using Notepad++ and have file with in ANSI UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

What is your client NLS lang? If you are running script in UTF-8 then it is supposed to be UTF-8. Otherwise save your file in single byte code page (not UTF8).